# Java ConcurrentModificationException with abstract super class

Tags: java, libgdx, concurrentmodification

So I understand why I get the error; I would like to know a work around if possible or an alternative!

So I have a class called `SpriteRenderable` which is used to sort and render all objects on screen, it contains the position and sprite for the instances.

```
public static ArrayList<SpriteRenderable> spriteRenderables;
```

`SpriteRenderable` also has a static function `Render(SpriteBatch batch)` which loops over this list to call the `update` function on each one.

```
public static void Render() {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    for (ListIterator<SpriteRenderable> iter = 
        spriteRenderables.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        SpriteRenderable spriteRenderable = iter.next();
        spriteRenderable.update(delta);
        spriteRenderable.sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    spriteBatch.end();
}

public abstract void update();
```

I have another class `Player` which extends the `SpriteRenderable` class, so it's automatically added to the static ArrayList, and updated every render cycle. This is the same as the `Gun` and `Bullet` class as well.

The `Gun` class and `Bullet` class extend `SpriteRenderable` as well. Within the `Player` classes update function, if `(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT))` then the Guns shoot method is called which in tern calls `Bullet shot = new Bullet();`

This works fine until Player is updated, and the player fires the gun; the instantiated bullets are added to the static ArrayList while looping through itself. Causing :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I've tried surrounding the foreach(SpriteRenderable) loop with a try and catch; however this ends up not rendering any of the sprites due to the exception.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're changing the state of a collection while you're iterating through it, something not allowed without an interator, but having said that, your overall program structure sounds possibly off, what with your heavy use of statics, and this could very well be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) in disguise. We need more code and info, a lot of both.

Comment: ArrayList is not threadsafe will cause the concurrent modification exception when you update the list while iterating.You can try CopyOnWriteArrayList which is a concurrent Collection class introduced in Java 5 Concurrency API.

Comment: Try using LibGDX's SnapshotArray so you can safely edit the array however you like while looping through it. Instructions for use are in its Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you iterate more through the list than modify it, you'd be good with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Any modifications during the lifetime of the iterator will not be visible to the iterator, however.